# No Such Instance currently exists at this OID netsnmp

Tags: c++, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I am trying to add a new service to SNMP agent. I am currently using SNMP v2 and have the agent currently running, however, when I try to send a request using snmpwalk, I get the following error: "No Such Instance currently exists at this OID". I have all the entries required in the MIB, and using snmpwalk for requesting other services works fine, except the one I am try to send a request to. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you do your SNMP walk from one node higher in the tree that the one failing you may get a clue as to what is wrong.

Comment: Which OID triggers that error message?

Comment: 253.8.74.x.x.x.7.43 works fine, however, when I try to add 253.8.74.x.x.x.7.45, I get the above error. Is there any table or mapping file which needs this entry?

Answer (score -1):

"No Such Instance currently exists at this OID" means just simply that.

The device you are querying does not support that specific OID

Comment: That's not what it means. It means "just simply that": no such instance exists at that OID. If the OID itself weren't supported then you'd get No Such Name instead.